# Centering image on my footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to center the logo image on my footer. I want it to be able to scale as the browser changes but stay inside the center. If anyone knows how I can fix this that would really help! Thank you! I really appreciate all of the help with this. I have figured it out now and I am good to go.

```css
.msum {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
/*Rest of Code*/

figure.stayssame {
  width: 100%;
}
figure video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
p {
  padding: 2%;
}
.video-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 15%;
}
/*ALL CODE FROM DESKTOP*/

figure.adjustable {
  width: 29%;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /*font-family: 'Courier New', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.squish {
  margin-right: 125px;
}
.text {
  padding: 5px;
}
.button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 20%
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #670809;
  height: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 9px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
header,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li.active a {
  background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #00E3FF;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*nav ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  
  padding: 1 px;
  
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1 px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: .55em;
  font-size: 5 px;
  float: right;
  
 }

nav ul li.active a {
 /*background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover {
 /*background-color:none;
  color:black;
  background-color:#00E3FF;
 
 }
 
 
 
 nav ul li a:visited {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none; 
 }
*/

form {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
/* header tags */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #013397;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00E3FF;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#box {
  background-color: #94DBEC;
}
hr.style2 {
  border-top: 3px double #00E3FF;
  width: 300px
}
section {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
img.adjustable {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 400px;*/
  margin: 1em;
  /*width: 90%;
 margin:5%;*/
}
#inner {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
.imgbox5 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox4 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox3 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox2 {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.imgbox {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#firstpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#secpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#thirdpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#fourthpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#primary {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#enroll {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*section{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 
 }*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: #670809;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /* text */
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
a,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side {
  left-margin: 10px;
  right-margin: 10px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
#headline {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 35%;
  color: #00E3FF;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#value {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/*.img{
border-width:thick;
 border-style:solid;
border-color:white;  
}

.column-right{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 }
.column-center{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 bottom: 18px;
 
 
 }
 
 .column-left{
 float: left;file:///Volumes/MMG/webfix/video/techpic1.jpg
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 

 }
 
 #left-box{
 
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
 
}
#middle-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;

}

#right-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
padding-bottom:135px;
}
.more {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 20px;
  right: 31px;
  background-color:white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 9px;
  width: 30%;
}
#button3, #button2{
color: black;
position:relative;
top: 36px;
right:36px; 
}

#button1{
color:black;
position:relative;
top: 155px;
right:36px; 
}

*/

/*NAV BAR*/

@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
 html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
main {
  padding: 2rem;
}
/***************** NAVIGATION ********************/

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #670809;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  flex: 1;
}
nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
nav a:hover {
  background:
  /*#adacac*/
  #555;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
nav input,
nav label {
  display: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
nav label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  transition: .4s;
}
nav label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\f0c9";
  text-align: center;
}
/*************** MEDIA QUERIES *******************/

nav ul {
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav li {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav label {
  display: block;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
}
#css-toggle-menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a id="enroll" href="https://www.mnstate.edu/eservices/"> Enroll Now</a>
  <div class="text">
     &copy; 2016</div>
  <br>
  <img class="msum" src="https://www.mnstate.edu/uploadedImages/Content/Marketing/logos/MSUM_Signature_Horiz_Color.jpg?n=808" alt="msum logo" />
</footer>
```

Comment: Just wondering why people can't use the tiny Tidy button?

Comment: @PraveenKumar not sure what you're talking about honestly

Comment: The code to be formatted. Now it looks tidier. Previously, it had so much whitespaces!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.msum {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    //add this
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: No explanation?

Comment: This worked seamlessly! Thank you so much for helping me figure this out! I really appreciate it!!! :) @GvM

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for `position: absolute` here. Do these to the `img.msum`:

- Remove `position: absolute;`
- Add `margin: auto;`

**Snippet**

```css
.msum {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
/*Rest of Code*/

figure.stayssame {
  width: 100%;
}
figure video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
p {
  padding: 2%;
}
.video-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 15%;
}
/*ALL CODE FROM DESKTOP*/

figure.adjustable {
  width: 29%;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /*font-family: 'Courier New', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.squish {
  margin-right: 125px;
}
.text {
  padding: 5px;
}
.button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 20%
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #670809;
  height: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 9px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
header,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li.active a {
  background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #00E3FF;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*nav ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  
  padding: 1 px;
  
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1 px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: .55em;
  font-size: 5 px;
  float: right;
  
 }

nav ul li.active a {
 /*background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover {
 /*background-color:none;
  color:black;
  background-color:#00E3FF;
 
 }
 
 
 
 nav ul li a:visited {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none; 
 }
*/

form {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
/* header tags */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #013397;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00E3FF;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#box {
  background-color: #94DBEC;
}
hr.style2 {
  border-top: 3px double #00E3FF;
  width: 300px
}
section {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
img.adjustable {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 400px;*/
  margin: 1em;
  /*width: 90%;
 margin:5%;*/
}
#inner {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
.imgbox5 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox4 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox3 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox2 {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.imgbox {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#firstpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#secpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#thirdpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#fourthpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#primary {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#enroll {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*section{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 
 }*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: #670809;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /* text */
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
a,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side {
  left-margin: 10px;
  right-margin: 10px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
#headline {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 35%;
  color: #00E3FF;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#value {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/*.img{
border-width:thick;
 border-style:solid;
border-color:white;  
}

.column-right{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 }
.column-center{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 bottom: 18px;
 
 
 }
 
 .column-left{
 float: left;file:///Volumes/MMG/webfix/video/techpic1.jpg
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 

 }
 
 #left-box{
 
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
 
}
#middle-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;

}

#right-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
padding-bottom:135px;
}
.more {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 20px;
  right: 31px;
  background-color:white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 9px;
  width: 30%;
}
#button3, #button2{
color: black;
position:relative;
top: 36px;
right:36px; 
}

#button1{
color:black;
position:relative;
top: 155px;
right:36px; 
}

*/

/*NAV BAR*/

@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
 html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
main {
  padding: 2rem;
}
/***************** NAVIGATION ********************/

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #670809;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  flex: 1;
}
nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
nav a:hover {
  background:
  /*#adacac*/
  #555;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
nav input,
nav label {
  display: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
nav label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  transition: .4s;
}
nav label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\f0c9";
  text-align: center;
}
/*************** MEDIA QUERIES *******************/

nav ul {
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav li {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav label {
  display: block;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
}
#css-toggle-menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a id="enroll" href="https://www.mnstate.edu/eservices/"> Enroll Now</a>
  <div class="text">
    MaKayla McLain-Graning &copy; 2016</div>
  <br>
  <img class="msum" src="https://www.mnstate.edu/uploadedImages/Content/Marketing/logos/MSUM_Signature_Horiz_Color.jpg?n=808" alt="msum logo" />
</footer>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: I apologize for getting back so late but this did work! Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this and help me! It really helped that you were very clear and straight-forward with your response. @Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Check out the snippet below. The big thing you were missing is using the CSS `left` and `transform` properties. (You'll notice I also included the vendor-prefixed variants of the `transform` property to ensure it works on all major browsers). Additionally, you'll notice I replaced the `absolute` positioning that you had set for the `.msum` CSS selector with `relative` positioning. This is more optimal in this case and will ensure your image does not overlap with the text also present in the footer.

```css
.msum {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;      /* Distribute from left-edge */
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  
  /* Center horizontally */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform:    translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform:     translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform:      translateX(-50%);
  transform:         translateX(-50%);
}
/*Rest of Code*/

figure.stayssame {
  width: 100%;
}
figure video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
p {
  padding: 2%;
}
.video-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 15%;
}
/*ALL CODE FROM DESKTOP*/

figure.adjustable {
  width: 29%;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /*font-family: 'Courier New', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.squish {
  margin-right: 125px;
}
.text {
  padding: 5px;
}
.button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 20%
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #670809;
  height: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 9px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
header,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li.active a {
  background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #00E3FF;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*nav ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  
  padding: 1 px;
  
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1 px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: .55em;
  font-size: 5 px;
  float: right;
  
 }

nav ul li.active a {
 /*background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover {
 /*background-color:none;
  color:black;
  background-color:#00E3FF;
 
 }
 
 
 
 nav ul li a:visited {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none; 
 }
*/

form {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
/* header tags */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #013397;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00E3FF;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#box {
  background-color: #94DBEC;
}
hr.style2 {
  border-top: 3px double #00E3FF;
  width: 300px
}
section {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
img.adjustable {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 400px;*/
  margin: 1em;
  /*width: 90%;
 margin:5%;*/
}
#inner {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
.imgbox5 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox4 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox3 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox2 {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.imgbox {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#firstpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#secpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#thirdpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#fourthpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#primary {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#enroll {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*section{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 
 }*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: #670809;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /* text */
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
a,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side {
  left-margin: 10px;
  right-margin: 10px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
#headline {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 35%;
  color: #00E3FF;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#value {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/*.img{
border-width:thick;
 border-style:solid;
border-color:white;  
}

.column-right{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 }
.column-center{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 bottom: 18px;
 
 
 }
 
 .column-left{
 float: left;file:///Volumes/MMG/webfix/video/techpic1.jpg
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 

 }
 
 #left-box{
 
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
 
}
#middle-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;

}

#right-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
padding-bottom:135px;
}
.more {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 20px;
  right: 31px;
  background-color:white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 9px;
  width: 30%;
}
#button3, #button2{
color: black;
position:relative;
top: 36px;
right:36px; 
}

#button1{
color:black;
position:relative;
top: 155px;
right:36px; 
}

*/

/*NAV BAR*/

@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
 html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
main {
  padding: 2rem;
}
/***************** NAVIGATION ********************/

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #670809;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  flex: 1;
}
nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
nav a:hover {
  background:
  /*#adacac*/
  #555;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
nav input,
nav label {
  display: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
nav label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  transition: .4s;
}
nav label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\f0c9";
  text-align: center;
}
/*************** MEDIA QUERIES *******************/

nav ul {
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav li {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav label {
  display: block;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
}
#css-toggle-menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a id="enroll" href="https://www.mnstate.edu/eservices/"> Enroll Now</a>
  <div class="text">
    MaKayla McLain-Graning &copy; 2016</div>
  <br>
  <img class="msum" src="https://www.mnstate.edu/uploadedImages/Content/Marketing/logos/MSUM_Signature_Horiz_Color.jpg?n=808" alt="msum logo" />
</footer>
```

Comment: You don't need both X, Y if you are not centering vertically.

Comment: Fair point, I have clarified it to use only the `translateX()` CSS function.

Comment: Thanks. It looks awesome. Do you think it's overkill to have a translate function when we know the widths?

Comment: Not really. In my projects, I usually have a class like `.img` with the same `position`, `left` and `transform` properties as used above. I find it to be a pretty useful construct given I can apply it to images all over the application and expect consistent/desired behavior. Do you have a different opinion?

Comment: Simple. When we know the width, then we just need to give a negative margin left of half the width. And it is easier, as older browsers do not support transform. This solution is only useful or better used for those elements, where the dimensions are unknown. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

```css
.msum {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
}
/*Rest of Code*/

figure.stayssame {
  width: 100%;
}
figure video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
p {
  padding: 2%;
}
.video-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -5%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 15%;
}
/*ALL CODE FROM DESKTOP*/

figure.adjustable {
  width: 29%;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /*font-family: 'Courier New', sans-serif;*/
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.squish {
  margin-right: 125px;
}
.text {
  padding: 5px;
}
.button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 20%
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #670809;
  height: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 9px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
header,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li.active a {
  background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #00E3FF;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*nav ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  
  padding: 1 px;
  
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1 px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: .55em;
  font-size: 5 px;
  float: right;
  
 }

nav ul li.active a {
 /*background-color: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover {
 /*background-color:none;
  color:black;
  background-color:#00E3FF;
 
 }
 
 
 
 nav ul li a:visited {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none; 
 }
*/

form {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
/* header tags */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #013397;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00E3FF;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#box {
  background-color: #94DBEC;
}
hr.style2 {
  border-top: 3px double #00E3FF;
  width: 300px
}
section {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
img.adjustable {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 400px;*/
  margin: 1em;
  /*width: 90%;
 margin:5%;*/
}
#inner {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
.imgbox5 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox4 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox3 {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.imgbox2 {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.imgbox {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#firstpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#secpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#thirdpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#fourthpara {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#primary {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
}
#enroll {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*section{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 
 }*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background-color: #670809;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  /* text */
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
a,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side {
  left-margin: 10px;
  right-margin: 10px;
}
object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
#headline {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 35%;
  color: #00E3FF;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#value {
  background-color: #5E5757;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/*.img{
border-width:thick;
 border-style:solid;
border-color:white;  
}

.column-right{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 }
.column-center{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 bottom: 18px;
 
 
 }
 
 .column-left{
 float: left;file:///Volumes/MMG/webfix/video/techpic1.jpg
 width: 30%;
 padding: 1%;
 
 

 }
 
 #left-box{
 
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
 
}
#middle-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;

}

#right-box{
 background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
border-radius:10px;
padding-bottom:135px;
}
.more {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 20px;
  right: 31px;
  background-color:white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 9px;
  width: 30%;
}
#button3, #button2{
color: black;
position:relative;
top: 36px;
right:36px; 
}

#button1{
color:black;
position:relative;
top: 155px;
right:36px; 
}

*/

/*NAV BAR*/

@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300");
 html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
main {
  padding: 2rem;
}
/***************** NAVIGATION ********************/

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #670809;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  flex: 1;
}
nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
nav a:hover {
  background:
  /*#adacac*/
  #555;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
nav input,
nav label {
  display: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
nav label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  transition: .4s;
}
nav label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\f0c9";
  text-align: center;
}
/*************** MEDIA QUERIES *******************/

nav ul {
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav li {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav label {
  display: block;
}
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
}
#css-toggle-menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a id="enroll" href="https://www.mnstate.edu/eservices/"> Enroll Now</a>
  <div class="text">
    MaKayla McLain-Graning &copy; 2016</div>
  <br>
  <img class="msum" src="https://www.mnstate.edu/uploadedImages/Content/Marketing/logos/MSUM_Signature_Horiz_Color.jpg?n=808" alt="msum logo" />
</footer>
```

Comment: This is a good technique. An explanation would be really better.